# is it any solution of failed to find provider in android?

Tags: android-xml

error is :

[2011-07-08 18:30:54 - Android2Wrox.com] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
[2011-07-08 18:30:54 - Android2Wrox.com] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-07-08 18:30:54 - Android2Wrox.com] Launch canceled!

--

i have facing more this type of error on when i implement two application in AndroidManifest.xml file: i have give that XML code :

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="Android2Wrox.comActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Android2Wrox"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

<application android:name="MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/image">

</application>
```

```
07-08 16:42:46.101: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:42:46.101: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:02.069: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:02.229: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:02.489: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:02.739: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:02.849: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:03.029: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:03.119: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:03.239: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:03.359: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:03.969: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:04.269: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:04.702: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 16:43:04.939: ERROR/ActivityThread(464): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
07-08 17:46:37.180: ERROR/DictionaryBackupAgent(196): Couldn't read from the cursor
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you requested an `INTERNET` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? I.e.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```